# Magento product CSV sheet is not import, just show loading image

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I just update my Magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.2 but after update i noticed that Magento import is not working. As i upload product CSV sheet thorough System --> Import/Export --> Import (method), it didn't show any error (in check data) after when click on import data then it just show loading image nothing else, when i cancel the process product are in back-end but products are not showing at front-end, also it's not asking for any indexing. I optimized the database and again create core_url, delete all logs, but any of them works.

Comment: Usually when the loading icon doesn't disappear, it means that the request, which does the import is finished probably with an error. Try to look at those requests in a web console to see the response. Maybe the php has just timed out or something similar is the problem.

Comment: web console doesn't show any error, i thought it's deadlock in tables so i clear all the logs and log tables also clear core_url, still the same problem.

Comment: Have you had a look at the log files? Magento logs in `var/log/`, or PHP error logs?

Comment: Use UTF-8, avoid ANSI

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a multi website installation check you are adding your products to your website.

Also check:

- Product `visibility`
- Product `status` (enabled/disabled)

Make sure you are not running out of memory while importing:
Set the following values for you PHP:

- memory_limit: `512M`
- max_execution_time: `600` (remember to lower this after your test)

Also try importing ust one product and see if it works.

Check in your `var/log` (both Magento and PHP) to see if you have any error report.